# 413: FULL head when pushing to Mercurial repository behind Nginx

Tags: mercurial, nginx

I have a Mercurial repository running on Scm-manager proxied behind Nginx. A variety of smaller repositories run fine, so the basic setup seems OK.

Additionally, this same box runs Owncloud. I've tweaked the client_max_body_size on the server to 1000M so large files can be transferred. This works, and I have a variety of large files syncing between the server and clients.

However, when I try pushing a large Mercurial repository for the first time (1007 commits vs. about 80 for the other largest on this system) I get the following:

abort: HTTP Error 413: FULL head

Everything I've read about 413 errors doesn't seem to apply. First, it recommends setting the body size, which I've stated is already at 1G. Next, this seems to apply that the header is too large, which makes sense given that it's probably trying to check 1000+ revisions in the remote repository.

Another thing I've encountered is large_client_header_buffers. I've set this to insanely huge values like "64 128k" on both the server and http levels (read something about it not working on servers) but that didn't change anything.

I also looked at the scm-manager logs but see nothing, so this seems to stop with Nginx.

Thoughts? Here is part of my Nginx server configuration:

```
server {
  server_name thewordnerd.info;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/thewordnerd.info.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/thewordnerd.info.key;
  root /srv/www/thewordnerd.info/public;
  client_max_body_size 1000M;
  location /scm {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080/scm;
    include         /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `HTTP Error: 413 (Request Entity Too Large)` on my attempt to push. Resolved by adding `client_max_body_size 2M;` to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Wondering if maybe `1000M` doesn't exceed the `client_max_body_size`...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the header buffer of the application server, this is because of mercurial uses very big headers. You have to increase the size of the header buffer and this application server specific. In case you are using the standalone version, you have to edit the server-config.xml and increase the requestHeaderSize value.

replace:

```
<Set name="requestHeaderSize">16384</Set>
```

with:

```
<Set name="requestHeaderSize">32768</Set>
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scmmanager/Afad4zXSx78